# Replacing calcium acetate with sodium polyacrylate for homemade Sterno?

Tags: polymers, applied-chemistry

I was researching making canned heat using denatured(ethyl) alcohol, water, and calcium acetate from scratch. 
However, it occured to me that sodium polyacrylate also absorbs water and alcohol and is pretty easy to retrieve by taking apart diapers. 
Would this substitution give the same effect as calcium acetate does?

Comment: Technically it may work, but I would be concerned by burning the sodium polyacrylate.